# AmCharts - Map - Prevent map panning outside viewport

Tags: amcharts

When moving around (Panning) an AmCharts map, we can move the map completely outside the viewport resulting in a white background with no clues about where the map has gone.
Is there a way to restrict this, or at least to detect it and recenter the map if it becomes invisible ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oups, found it ...

There is a preventDragOut option that does just that :

https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#preventDragOut

```
 var map = AmCharts.makeChart("maps", {"preventDragOut": true, ... } );
```